# Tools to document Mason and Perl code?

Tags: perl, documentation, mason

Other than POD, what are the tools available to document my Perl and Mason code? What do you use and what tools are available to help me?

Comment: Isn't there an obscure built in operator in Perl that does it? It has one for everything else...

Comment: being new i dont know what perl operator you say you use so can you tell what it is?

Answer (score 1):

For the documentation in Mason, there is the `<%doc>` tag. Use it like so:

```
<%doc>
some text
here
</%doc>
```

The `doc` tag is treated as a comment. see [Mason::Manual::Syntax](http://search.cpan.org/~jswartz/Mason/lib/Mason/Manual/Syntax.pod)